# Diferença entre datas para achar a quantidade de dias

Tags: php, data, diff

Olá, amigos. Eu tenho um código em que calculo a diferença em dias entre duas datas. Eu preciso passar as variáveis para a instância dos objetos, mas só dá certo se eu colocar a string manualmente.

(1) Desta forma abaixo dá certo:

```
$origin = new DateTime('2017-03-03');
$target = new DateTime('2017-04-06');
$interval = $origin->diff($target);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

(2) Mas desta forma abaixo, que é a que eu preciso, não dá certo:

```
$origin = new DateTime($dataInicio);
$target = new DateTime($dataFim);
$interval = $origin->diff($target);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

A froma (1) me retorna 34 dias, mas a forma (2), quando passo os parâmetros com as mesmas datas de (1), dá um valor +209 days, dá 6 meses e 26 dias . Como eu resolveria isso? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Duas coisas:

1) as suas variáveis realmente são strings?
2) se sim para a pergunta de cima, o formato delas corresponde ao necessário?

Answer (score 0):

Qual o formato que você está recebendo nas variáveis `$dataInicio` e `$dataFim`?

Eu rodei este código e a conta sai corretamente.

```
$dataInicio = '2020-03-03';
$dataFim = '2020-04-06';
$origin = new DateTime($dataInicio);
$target = new DateTime($dataFim);
$interval = $origin->diff($target);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Esse aí que você executou roda corretamente. Eu recebo as datas do banco de dados no formato yyyy-mm-dd, e quando coloco nas variáveis $dataInicio e $datafim, não funciona do mesmo jeito. Eu faço $dataInicio = $linha['DataIncio'] e $dataFim = $linha['DataFim'], porém não dá certo.